# Set will not display in my error message but List will

Tags: apex

I am trying to display a list of Opportunity names in my error message, When using the code below the opportunity displays properly but I would like to get rid of duplicate values, When I switch the List to a Set to avoid duplicates, nothing shows.

this works but shows duplicates:

```
       if(opli.size() > 0){
       List<String> opnames = new List<String>(); 
        for(OpportunityLineItem o: opli){
            opnames.add(o.Opportunity.Name);

        }
        System.debug(opnames);
        Trigger.new[0].addError('All Support Line Items Need A Date Populated In order For Opportunity To Close Check:' + opnames + ' To see if all dates are populated');

    }
```

this does not work, the error message shows but without the opportunity.

```
        if(opli.size() > 0){
       Set<String> opnames = new Set<String>(); 
        for(OpportunityLineItem o: opli){
            opnames.add(o.Opportunity.Name);

        }
        System.debug(opnames);
        Trigger.new[0].addError('All Support Line Items Need A Date Populated In order For Opportunity To Close Check:' + opnames + ' To see if all dates are populated');

    }
```

Comment: I would avoid type coercion in general as it truncates the  results. You might consider using `JSON.serialize(collection)` instead.

Comment: This pattern is going to get you in trouble as the addError should be applied to each member of Trigger.new where the error applies, not just Trigger.new[0. For example, when running dataloader, which supports allorNothing = false, errors should be set only on the elements of the batch where the invalid data applies

Comment: You can try explicitly calling toString() method on the set as below:

Trigger.new[0].addError( 'All Support Line Items Need A Date Populated In order For Opportunity To Close Check:' + opnames.toString() + ' To see if all dates are populated');

If that doesn't work, I would assume it's being escaped and would try the addError(errorMsg, escape) version and set escape to false. Note that this will work only in classic environment.